# Sequence of Holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $\Omega$ be open and connected. Suppos that a sequence
>   $$\{f_n : \Omega \to \mathbb{C} : f_n \mbox{ is holomorphic and injective in $\Omega$ }\}$$
>   Converges uniformly to a function $f$ on every compact subset of $\Omega$. Prove that if $f$ is not a constant in $\Omega$, then $f$ is injective in $\Omega$.

First I proved that $f$ is holomorphic.

Suppose that $f$ is not injective.

There are distinct point $z_1,z_2$ in $\Omega$.

Then there are path from $z1$ to $z2$ lying in $\Omega$.
Then... I can't tell you How to solve.

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you know Hurwitz theorem ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the open mapping theorem? It would help here.